# Can algorithms have the same best- and worst-case time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

Is it possible for an algorithm/program to have the same worst-case and best-case time?

For example:

```
public static int factorial(int number)
{
    factorial = 1; 
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) 
        factorial = factorial * i;
}
```

It's a program segment for the factorial problem, and I was trying to solve for the time complexity. It seems to have no worst and best case time, since whatever input you may have it will still go through the rest of the code, unlike when you have if-else statements.

If that's the case should I assume that what ever I get from this code it would be the best, worst and average case time?

Did I get this right?

```
public static int factorial(int number)
    {
        factorial = 1;                   // 1
        for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)    // 1+3n
            factorial = factorial * i;   // 2
        return factorial;                // 1
    }
```

Worst Case/Best Case:
 3n+5

Big – O :
O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case when `"number"` is fixed, your program has no worst or best case - it always does `"number"` iterations, so it has a linear complexity.
For formal mathematical definitions see these articles: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms 
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: so can i assume that it is the worst and best case?

Comment: oh..i see...im still kinda confused with that one..:) thanks for answering! :)

Comment: i have a follow up question..its up in my question...bottom part

Answer (score 3):

Of course.  Big O describes an upper bound, while little o describes a lower bound on some asymptotic quantity (such as the time complexity of an algorithm).  There is actually a special notation for giving bounds which are asymptotically tight (which is what you get when the Big o is the same as the little o), which is called big theta notation.

Comment: not exact. Big O is the upper bound, little O is the lower bound and theta is the aggregation of both, but that is is far as the definitions go (in layman's terms). But, you can define a Theta function for worst case computation, best case computation, etc...

Comment: @Yaneeve:  But of course!  The same notation can be used in many situations outside of asymptotic time complexity analysis (such as number theory or real analysis).  I edited the answer to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the complexity for the bast case is the same as the worst case = O(n).
Exactly for the reason you pointed out. No matter what the input is, the algorithm always performs the same actions (no if/else).